# Google.com SSL Ciphers - How to capture which ones they are using?

Tags: nginx, ssl, openssl

I would like to use the same SSL Ciphers Google.com uses - in order for maximum browser compatibility.

I'm aware that ssllabs.com shows them, but I have no idea how to translate them for use in Nginx via the "ssl_ciphers" config option.

https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=google.com&s=74.125.224.8&hideResults=on

Any ideas what I would need to use to make this happen?

Comment: I know that it does not answer your question, but I think this is what you want: Have a look at the paper from [bettercrypto.org](https://bettercrypto.org), they provide a CipherSuite with broad compatibility (for business environments) while also giving a preferred ordering, so the best cipher is negotiated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a list of ciphers supported by your version of OpenSSL (and thus by nginx) call `openssl ciphers -V` on the machine where nginx is running. To translate between the syntax used by OpenSSL and the syntax you see in the SSLLabs results have a look at the [man page for the ciphers command](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/ciphers.html#CIPHER-SUITE-NAMES) where you will find the translations like:

```
 TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA            AES128-SHA
```

Then simply concatenate the translated ciphers with ':' for your ciphers string. Please note that the order is relevant.

But, as you might see the rating from SSLLabs for google's server is 'B' because they still support SSL 3.0 and RC4. So instead of simply copying the ciphers (and forgetting to update them once google does) you might better follow the advice from [Mozilla](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS#Recommended_configurations) where several cipher combinations are shown and where they also explain in which cases which combination is useful.

Comment: I'm currently using Mozilla's "backward compatibility" ciphers, but I am unable to enable my 2048 bit "dhparams.pem" file without breaking support for older browsers. I noticed Google is able to use it - without breaking support with their ciphers.

Comment: @BrianSmith: I see the problem. Google has simply disabled all DHE ciphers, which are bad anyway if you care about performance. Thus only modern browsers will get forward secrecy by using the ECDHE ciphers.